# Can WiFi interfere with FireWire PCI card?

Tags: wireless-networking, audio, firewire

A year ago I upgraded my PC and replaced my motherboard with a cheap one which lacks a onboard wifi and firewire. To compensate this I've purchased a tp-link 300mbps wireless n adapter and a pci firewire.

Now I recently got back to audio recording with my FireWire audio interface and I've noticed massive audio glitches when routing audio via my audio interface when my WiFi was enabled.
I have now to disconnect the WiFi to be able to properly record audio.

The drivers of both WiFi and FireWire interface are up to date. Can WiFi cause an interference on FireWire? The antennas are in deed in a close proximity to the FireWire card.

I am not sure whether it affects the FireWire cable or the card itself. I have no replacement for the FireWire cable but I would expect the cable to be of high quality as it was packed with my audio interface (~800€).

The old configuration used LAN and everything was on board anyway, so I have never noticed such issues there.

Comment: Are the pci-cards sitting next to eachother? If your mobo allows  it you can try rearranging them so they are further apart. But i suspect this will not eliminate the problem as the culprit will propably be EMI-related and the wifi-card is marked as high-power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does indeed sound as if your Wi-Fi transceiver is interfering with your FireWire interface.  However, I doubt that you’re getting noticeable crosstalk on your audio cable – this is digital audio, after all; I think it’s much more likely that the PCI cards themselves are improperly shielded, causing crosstalk between circuitry on the two cards.  This would jibe with your previous experience, assuming your old hardware was shielded correctly.  To see if this is the case, orient the antenna orthogonally to the audio cable, and then parallel to the audio cable.  Is there any difference in the frequency of glitching on the audio line when the antenna is orthogonal versus when it is parallel?  If so, you’re seeing crosstalk between the antenna and the audio cable; if not, you’ve got some other problem.

Another very real possibility is that the two PCI cards have an interrupt collision, so each is responding to interrupts targeted at the other.  I’d think you’d be seeing a lot of packet loss if this were the case, but it’s possible that the Wi-Fi card has hardware to eliminate spurious interrupts, while the FireWire card does not.  This is not as uncommon as you would hope, especially with a cheap motherboard.  Check the IRQ settings in your BIOS or your operating system, and see if you’ve got multiple devices assigned the same IRQ.  (On Linux, you can check /proc/interrupts.)

Comment: There is no difference when orienting the antennas. However what I didn't mention is that the interferences are not constantly present. They occur every couple of seconds. Sometimes the entire audio is just cut off. Sometimes its just noise. The device manager tells me that they use different IRQs (0x12 and 0x11) and it says no conflicts. Can there be a BIOS collision even if they use different IRQs in windows? I'll try to separate the cards further away, however there is already a USB hub pci card in between and not many slots left.

Comment: Well I've separated them and placed an older sound-card in-between. Still interference. Tested the old sound-card and I think there was slight interference, but very little. Maybe it is better shielded.

Comment: A search for this kind of problem on the (excellent) http://www.gearslutz.com/ audio-related forums revealed similar issues, dating back to 2008. See http://www.gearslutz.com/board/music-computers/483157-wifi-messing-up-audio-interface.html and http://www.gearslutz.com/board/music-computers/102367-ground-problem-digital-noise-firewire-audio-interface-synth.html. In short, disable wifi while recording, or switch to a non-firewire interface. I suspect you use an RME, these seem to suffer the most. Shame really, they are good interfaces beside this issue (mine's 8 years ols and still aok)

Comment: Some more reading suggests switching to a usb wifi-interface. Maybe the best option in your case, cheaper than a new decent audio interface.